# Is there any react native library to check for contacts which is marked as Favorite/starred?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, contacts, react-native-contacts

I am working on a project, where I have to fetch phone contact details and display as list view in UI using react-native. Used react-native-contacts library to fetch  the phone contact details.

My problem is react-native-contacts does not provide any info about whether the contact is marked as favorite. Can anyone help me is there any library to get favorite details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-native-contacts library does not provide any flexibly to query on favorites list.
Native bridge must be used to fetch favorites list.